# Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /includes/lib/TWIG/enviornment.php(331):eval() d code on line 49

Tags: php, twig

i am trying to populate html select option with values fetched from database using TWIG templating. i tried everything which came across me in google but i failed to get the solution so far i did in.
controller: index.php

```
require_once 'includes/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();  

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('./');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('components/epayroll/new/empView.xhtml');  

require_once 'components/epayroll/new/empClass.php';
$objEmp = new Employee();
$data=$objEmp::getAllCourt();
//print_r($data);
echo $template->render(array (
'data' => $data,
'msg' => 'courts not found',
 ));
```

in modal section: empClass.php

```
class Employee {  

public function getAllCourt()
{
    require_once 'components/konec2DB.php';
    $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $getcourt = "select ddo_court from cms_ddo";
    $sql = "select ddo_court from cms_ddo";
    $sth = $DBH->query($sql);
    $data = array();
       while ($row = $sth->fetchObject()){
            $data[] = $row;
                }   
     return $data;
}
}
```

in view section of TWIG: empView.xhtml

> ```
>    <td class='input'>  <select id="slctcourt">
>    <option value="">--Select--</option>  
>         {% for court in data %}  
>         <option value=" ">{{ court }}</option>
>         {% else %}
>         <option value="">{{ msg }}</option>
>         {% endfor %}
>         </select></td>
> ```

please help me out i am trying from last four days to get it solved. so far i have tried

```
'data' => (string)$data,//casting
```

then i tried

```
'data' => $data->ddo_court,//this shows msg "courts not found"
```

then i tried

```
'data' => $data[0], // this populates select option box with value 'Array'
```

some where i found to implement the iterator interface to iterate the object and that is beyond my skills.

please help me out